# Jquery Update Function like Unity3D

Tags: jquery, function

My variable *nim* is not updating the seconds call

```
$( "#upbutton" ).click(function() {
    var nim = $("a").css("margin-top").replace("px", "");
    nim+=70;
    $("#moved").css('margin-top',nim+'px');
});
```

*nim* = 70 and does not change.

Comment: `$("a").css("margin-top")` returns `margin-top` of the first `a` element in the DOM, you don't update the property, what do you expect? Store the property's value outside the click handler and use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nim = $("a").css("margin-top").replace("px", "");

$( "#upbutton" ).click(function() {
    nim += 70;
    $("#moved").css( 'margin-top', nim + 'px' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the value for nim from the first  tag in the document, and then you're updating it on the element with the moved id.

Shouldn't you be getting it from the same element you're setting it on if you want that element to move?